# ag-grid ServerSideInfiniteScroll=false breaks pagination

Tags: angular, ag-grid

When setting AgGrid's `serverSideInfiniteScroll = false`, for some reason the grid ignores the `row amount` property in the `params.success` callback of `getRows` and set the number of rows received as the total number of rows, therefore only allows one page.

the reason for setting `serverSideInfiniteScroll` to `false` was in order to load all of the rows received immediately, and not wait until they're being scrolled.

I'd like to get any assistance/suggestions regarding this issue.

Comment: I guess, when the infinite scroll is off, datasource will request the whole dataset in one request

Comment: @mashi that's what I think as well. do you have any idea how can I load the entire page in a different way?
I rather just load it without rendering it, if it's possible (i.e have it in the cacheBlock but not in the DOM, I guess)

Comment: just have `paginationPageSize` and  `cacheBlockSize` equal, but keep infinite scroll as true. In this case it will initiate one request per page.

Comment: I've actually tried, it but I'm also using row grouping. I figured that it may be my problem so I set `cacheBlockSize` to a bigger number than the `paginationPageSize`, but it still didn't work. (My guess is that ag-grid is setting `paginationPageSize`'s size as the maximum of `cacheBlockSize`?

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you use server-side row model then? if you want to get everything in one request, together with all groups. Probably Client-side model is what you need?

Comment: @mashi thanks for keeping the discussion, I'll ellaborate.
I don't need all of the data, I need some of the data (page size chunks of group objects), but when this one chunk come from the server I want to be able to make actions on any row.
Let's say I have totally 100 objects in my DB, page size is 50, I get only 50 objects in the first API call, each object represting a group in ag-grid, so far all is fine. but then I want to select the 50th row programatically, I can't because it's not even loaded to the cacheBlock.

Comment: @mashi so I do need SSRM, but for the data that does come from server, **for a specific page** I want to load it all at once, even if it's not rendered yet.

Comment: with pageSize 50 and blockSize 50, it will request 50 objects. How do you select the row?

Comment: How many rows do you actually have? It better be more than 10k-50k or you should probably just use the client-side model.

Comment: @thirtydot in the highest amount we have encountered so far, it can get up to 18k **group** rows (each group contains around 5 rows in average).

Comment: @mashi yes on second thought I don't think it's related to the grouping since I'm seeing in the cache blockstate all of the groups names when it's fully loaded. the question is why I'm getting about 11rows loaded (before scrolling) instead of 50 when my pagesize and cacheblock size are 50?
if I use domLayout of 'autoHeight' for example, I do get all of the 50 rows loaded. but I think that it's also rendering them, something which I'd rather avoid if not necessary.

Comment: If you dont see your 50th row rendered in the DOM, that is b/c off row Virtualization. Grid renders only what is visible in the viewport plust some row buffer (10 rows). Virtualization can be turned off

Comment: @mashi yes, I'm aware of it. I'm saying that I don't want rows to be rendered (as in available in the DOM), but only loaded as an object in the ag-grid's state..